# Skimage.transform.resize outputs a misaligned image map

Tags: python, image-resizing, scikit-image

I am working on a segmentation model and I want to resize the logit output to the original image size.

I am using skimage.transform.resize function to resize the logits. But I have observed the upsampled logit mask obtained is shifted by a few pixel. could anyone please explain why does that happen? Also, is there any alternate to this?

```
prediction = np.squeeze(output[i, :, :])
raw_output_up = skresize((prediction-prediction.min())/(prediction.max()-prediction.min()), (image.shape[1], image.shape[2]), order=3, mode='reflect')
              raw_output_up = (raw_output_up * (prediction.max()-prediction.min())) + prediction.min()            
              raw_output_up[raw_output_up>=0.5]=1
              raw_output_up[raw_output_up<0.5]=0
```

Comment: Here'a a sample image depicting the issue:

![sample-image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nEZ2q14zE-PWaEA9w3CSECX7j2g6rkFO/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code at first glance. Could you provide the raw image and the prediction? I wonder if the prediction itself is shifted already. The error might be upstream.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Juan! I did verify that the original prediction aligns well. There is no shift observed in the network prediction.

Comment: Could you provide example images to use as input for the code above?

Comment: Hi Juan, Thanks for your reply. Sure! ![Raw image prediction](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LQQFfI75BWCeIKob5ChtqzTySWzVKHJU/view?usp=sharing)    ![Ground truth](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fBmuPmn6ZophojjOgOo7lgBlAIRba7c2/view?usp=sharing)      ![skimage.transform.resize](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16FfD0BLhYcvKhY4di2-RMiIv6jO6BixY/view?usp=sharing) ![tensorflow bilinear-interpolation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-zOxDPJjoliVqgBj8myX6d8QPYlgODdA/view?usp=sharing)     ![raw_label](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-crWCHwx7MdT9Z9bO-RAQjYNojKXe_4Z/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Using tensorflow bilinear interpolation helped. It aligns well with the ground truth.